# %g in Printf does not give fixed decimal places like %f or %e

Tags: go

According to [these docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) `%g` is `%e for large exponents, %f otherwise`. However, when I do:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a float64 = 2.0
    fmt.Printf("%f\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("%e\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("%g\n", a)
}
```

I get:

```
2.000000
2.000000e+00
2
```

Why does the output for `%g` not contain fixed decimal places like `%e` or `%f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> Printing
>
> The default precision for %g is the smallest number of digits
>   necessary to identify the value uniquely

For the value 2.0 that is one digit giving the value 2.